# Push data to parent in a recursive function

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, recursion

I have the following object:

```
let model = {
   id: 1,
   name: "model 1",
   children: [{
         id: 2,
         name: "sub model 1",
         children: [{
               id: 3,
               name: "criteria 1",
               isCriteria: true,
               answer: {
                  mark: 4
               }
            },
            {
               id: 4,
               name: "criteria 2",
               isCriteria: true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         id: 5,
         name: "sub model 2",
         children: [{
               id: 6,
               name: "criteria 3",
               isCriteria: true,
               answer: {
                  mark: 4
               }
            },
            {
               id: 7,
               name: "criteria 4",
               isCriteria: true,
               answer: {
                  mark: 2
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
};
```

I want in result the following object:

```
{
   name: "model 1",
   answer: {
      mark: 3.5,
      completion: 75
   },
   children: [{
         name: "sub model 1",
         answer: {
            mark: 4,
            completion: 50
         },
         children: [{
               name: "criteria 1",
               isCriteria: true,
               answer: {
                  mark: 4
               }
            },
            {
               name: "criteria 2",
               isCriteria: true
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         name: "sub model 2",
         answer: {
            mark: 3,
            completion: 100
         },
         children: [{
               name: "criteria 3",
               isCriteria: true,
               answer: {
                  mark: 4
               }
            },
            {
               name: "criteria 4",
               isCriteria: true,
               answer: {
                  mark: 2
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

**EXPLICATION:**
I want to push to every parent the following answer object:

```
{
    mark: the sum of marks of all children/total of children (exclude children with no answer),
    completion: (the sum of children with answer/total children) * 100
}
```

**!! NB: The depth of the object is unknown.**

I tried the following function, But it adds the answer object only to the first parent before last depth

```
function loopThoughModelChildren(node, parent) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    };
    if (node.isCriteria) {
        if (!parent.tempAnswer) {
            parent.tempAnswer = [];
        }
        parent.tempAnswer.push({ child: node.id, answer: node.answer });
    }
    if (node.children)
        node.children.forEach(child => loopThoughModelChildren(child, node));
}
```

Comment: Why did you [delete the previous version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60869484/push-data-to-parent-in-a-recursive-function) of this question instead of just adding your approach?

Comment: I thought it's better to open new one since the other one was seen by many and may not return to answer since it was not properly asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach with a look to the children property.

Then generate new nodes and assign the answers.

```js
function convert(node) {
    if (!node.children) return node;
    var marks = 0,
        completions = 0,
        count = 0,
        children = node.children.map(node => {
            node = convert(node);
            if (node.answer) {
                marks += node.answer.mark;
                completions += node.answer.completion || 100;
                count++;
            }
            return node;
        });
    return { ...node, answer: { mark: marks / count, completion: completions / node.children.length }, children };
}

var model = { id: 1, name: "model 1", children: [{ id: 2, name: "sub model 1", children: [{ id: 3, name: "criteria 1", isCriteria: true, answer: { mark: 4 } }, { id: 4, name: "criteria 2", isCriteria: true }] }, { id: 5, name: "sub model 2", children: [{ id: 6, name: "criteria 3", isCriteria: true, answer: { mark: 4 } }, { id: 7, name: "criteria 4", isCriteria: true, answer: { mark: 2 } }] }] },
    result = convert(model);

   console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```